# Children component already displayed

Tags: angular

below you can see my routes and I want to work with child routes. But my problem is that the content of the child component is already displayed on the UI. I am using

```
this.route.navigate()
```

to change the route and this I will need it.

How can I display the route only if I navigate to it?

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: StartComponent,
    children: [
      { path: ':id', component: TestComponent }
    ]
  },
  {path: '**', component: StartComponent}
];
```

I have also recognised that my component is not in my dom:

[image]

Comment: id can be null as well. So indirectly when you are on startComponent, even without id you are already on child as well

Comment: Change your TestComponent path to something like test/:id

Comment: I did it but still see the content. I have add the test component <app-test></app-test> to my start component. Is that correct?

Comment: No you must not add it to the html :)

Comment: @NoahTony Can you provide stackblitz.com demo for your issue

Answer (score 0):

```html
When u want to show ur child component ?
if after getting id then you can add condition in html like:
<span *ngIf="id"> 
 <app-test></app-test>
</span>
```